# how can i save each td value to a variable using curl

Tags: php, curl

i just started using curl, please tell me how can i save the td value or innerhtml into a variable. here is my code:

```
$xx = "mylink.html";
$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $xx);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$strPage = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);

  $pattern = '#<tbody>(.*?)</tbody>#';
  if( preg_match($pattern, $strPage, $match)){
    $catch = $match[0];
    print_r($match[0]);
  }else{
    echo 'Could not find it';
  }
```

here is the output:

```
<tbody class="highlighted"><tr class="xx"><td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td><td>value4</td><td>value5</td></tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be:

```
$var = '<tbody class="highlighted"><tr class="xx"><td>value1</td><td>value2</td><td>value3</td><td>value4</td><td>value5</td></tr></tbody>';

preg_match_all("/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/", $var,$matches); print_r($matches);
```

Where the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <td>value1</td>
            [1] => <td>value2</td>
            [2] => <td>value3</td>
            [3] => <td>value4</td>
            [4] => <td>value5</td>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value3
            [3] => value4
            [4] => value5
        )

)
```